# bgfx not setting background correctly

Tags: c++, bgfx

I am having a problem with bgfx graphics framework. This problem causes nothing to be rendered, and the background isn't being set to the correct color.

```
#include <bgfx/bgfx.h>
#include <bgfx/platform.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>

const int width = 800;
const int height = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Hello, bgfx!", NULL, NULL);

    bgfx::PlatformData pd;
    pd.nwh = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
    bgfx::setPlatformData(pd);

    bgfx::Init bgfxInit;
    bgfxInit.type = bgfx::RendererType::Count;
    bgfxInit.resolution.width = width;
    bgfxInit.resolution.height = height;
    bgfxInit.resolution.reset = BGFX_RESET_VSYNC;
    bgfx::init(bgfxInit);

    bgfx::setViewClear(0, BGFX_CLEAR_COLOR | BGFX_CLEAR_DEPTH, 0x443355FF, 1.0f, 0);
    bgfx::setViewRect(0, 0, 0, width, height);

    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Submit empty draw call
        bgfx::touch(0);

        // Render frame
        bgfx::frame();
    }

    // Cleanup
    bgfx::shutdown();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, if you are struggling with this. Instead of defining the platform data object, then doing `bgfx::setPlatformData`, set it inside of the init object.

Instead of:

```
bgfx::PlatformData pd;
pd.nwh = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
bgfx::setPlatformData(pd);
```

Do:

```
bgfx::Init bgfxInit;
bgfxInit.platformData.nwh = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
bgfxInit.type = bgfx::RendererType::Direct3D12;
bgfxInit.resolution.width = width;
bgfxInit.resolution.height = height;
bgfxInit.resolution.reset = BGFX_RESET_VSYNC;
bgfx::init(bgfxInit);
```